# Horizontally align an html5 audio element in a div

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-audio

I got this simple div:

```
#div-2 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

and an html5 audio element in the body of my page:

```
<div ID="div-2">
        <audio id="a1" src="../../audio/sound_files/mystuff.ogg"></audio>
</div>
```

I would like the audio element (that is, the audio controls displayed to the user) to be horizontally centered in the div. Please note I can't specify a width attribute for the audio controls or the audio elements (I tried, did nothing), and as a general rule I don't know the audio controls width (in pixels) between browsers (so I can't adjust the width attribute in the div).

Is there a way to do this either in CSS or, alternatively, in Javascript? It would be a bonus if someone could point me to a relevant resource on the web.

Comment: "I would like the audio element (that is, the audio controls displayed to the user) to be horizontally centered in the div" is there other content in the div (you don't show any here). If not, then the div will not be any wider than the audio element, so it would be "centered" no matter how you try to align it within the div.

Comment: Simply `#div-2 { text-align: center }` works in Chrome. Didn't test anywhere else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#div-2 {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Also if you are using the browser audio controls then remember to add `controls` to the tag, like so:

```
<audio id="a1" src="../../audio/sound_files/mystuff.ogg" controls></audio>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly (and, yes, I had "controls", but I omitted in the first post).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div align="center" id="player">
<audio controls>
<source src="name.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Unsupported browser!
</audio>
</div>
```