# Center HTML 5 Audio Players for All Browsers

Tags: css, html

I tried code like this:

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto;">
   <audio controls ....>
       ....
   </audio>
</div>
```

but this will not center the audio player because the div will expand to take up all available space. Is there a good way to center the audio player on EVERY browser without breaking it?

Comment: Why dont you set the width of the DIV to 100% and set the style for audio to margin: 0 auto; and if see if that works.

Comment: Try this link [Horizontally align an html5 audio element in a div][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232480/horizontally-align-an-html5-audio-element-in-a-div

Comment: @Adrift I don/t know if `inline-block` with `text-align` is 100% proper, but it works. If you post an answer, I shall accept.

Answer (score 9):

Try using `flexbox` with something like the following:

```
# HTML    
<div class='audio-container'>
   <audio controls>
   </audio>
</div>

#CSS
.audio-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

You can check it here https://jsbin.com/tojidar/edit?html,css,output

This should work fine on all the modern browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Style the audio element to `display: block; margin 0 auto;`. No need for a wrapper. Like this:

```html
<div>
    <audio controls style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;"></audio>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: table` on the audio component container, this will fit to the size of the audio component and `margin: 0 auto` will then center it:

```html
<div style="margin: 0 auto; display: table;">
   <audio controls ....>
       ....
   </audio>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just messing around with EJ-Media's stuff on YouTube and ran into the same desire.  This is no doubt a really blunt way to pull off what you are trying, maybe this:

```
<audio controls="audiocontrols"  style="display:block;margin:auto; text-align: center">
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the audio in a div:

HTML:

```
     <div class="container-fluid audioCenter">
            <audio controls>
                 <source src="audios/LearningToChooseYourThoughtsBreathTechnique.mov" 
                     type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
      .audioCenter{margin: 10px auto; width: 320px;}
```

Comment: There is (Or was) no guarantee the user is using bootstrap, I would suggest you that you state this requires bootstrap to work, as described [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container)

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div align="center">
<audio controls src="media/sample.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
</div>

or

<div align="center">
<audio controls>
<source src="media/sample.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
</div>
```

Comment: Code is always good, but it's also helps to include some comments or context about how your solution addresses the original question.