# How to centre/center html audio player to middle of webpage?

Tags: html, css, web, audio, github-pages

## Problem

**I have been trying to centre/center my HTML audio player to be in the centre/center of my GitHub Pages static website.** I have tried this in HTML and CSS. I have deleted my cache a few times to make sure that isn't the root of my problems. Chrome Browser / Mac OS 10.14.

## Code Snippet

```
<div class="audio">
   <audio controls>
      <source src="etc.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
   </audio>
</div>
```

## Attempts so far

### Attempt #1 - create a 'center' class and apply inline

Top of code (in style tags):

```
  .center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Bottom of code: `<source src="etc.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" class="center"/>`

### Attempt #2 - add id tag to audio player and align text to center

Top of code (in style tags) :

```
#audio {
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Bottom of code:  `<source id="audio" src="etc.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>`

### Attempt #3 - add div tags around audio player and align text to center

Top of code (in style tags):

```
  #audio {
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Bottom of code:

```
<div class="audio">
   <audio controls>
      <source src="etc.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
   </audio>
</div>
```

### Attempt #4 - vertically align text to center

Top of code (in style tags):

```
  #audio {
    vertical-align: center;
  }
```

Bottom of code:

```
<div class="audio">
   <audio controls>
      <source src="etc.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
   </audio>
</div>
```

### Attempt #5 - justify content to center

Top of code (in style tags):

```
#audio {
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

Bottom of code:

```
<div class="audio">
   <audio controls>
      <source src="etc.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
   </audio>
</div>
```

### Attempt #6 - align self to center

Top of code (in style tags):

```
#audio {
    align-self: center;
  }
```

Bottom of code:

```
<div class="audio">
   <audio controls>
      <source src="etc.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
   </audio>
</div>
```

### Attempt #7 - display audio player as inline block

Top of code (in style tags):

```
  #audio {
    align-self: center;
     display: inline-block;
  }
```

Bottom of code:

```
<div class="audio">
   <audio controls>
      <source src="etc.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
   </audio>
</div>
```

### Attempt #8 - wrapping the audio player in a table

```
  <div style="margin: 0 auto; display: table;">
    <audio controls>
      <source src="etc.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    </audio>
  </div>
```

### Attempt #9 - adding an audio container class and applying it inline

Top of code (in style tags):

```
.audio-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center 
}
```

Bottom of code:

```
  <div class='audio-container'>
    <audio controls>
      <source src="etc.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    </audio>
  </div>
```

## What I haven't attempted

- Adding so much padding that the audio player ends up in the centre/center of the page

## Sources of research

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)
- A generous number of StackOverflow threads
- W3C docs

## Solution - *IMPORTANT!* Updated 13/03/2019

From Sandip Nirmal's answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823868/center-html-5-audio-players-for-all-browsers) - also attempt #9 after deleting cache

Top of code (in style tags):

```
 .audio-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center 
}
```

Bottom of code:

```
  <div class="audio-container">
    <audio controls>
      <source src="etc.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    </audio>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the css like this:

```
.audio{
  width:100%;
}
.audio audio{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}
```

The "display: table;" is what does the trick.

Comment: @629060311 Welcome to Stackoverflow :)
If any of the answers answered your question, you should consider marking it as an answer.
More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks for the heads up and the welcome! :) I've marked it :D

Answer (score 0):

First of it should be

```
audio{
:
}  or `.audio{...}`
```

Since #audio target IDs meanwhile `audio` targets elements and `.audio` targets class with the value 'audio'

This is how I would have done it

```
audio{
width: 100%;
}

.audio{
width:500px /* relative units are actually better so consider using rem,em or %*/
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on relative units :) really helpful